# What's a word that means a brainteaser or puzzle so easy that you must be "inattentive" if you can't solve it and yet some normal people can't?

Tags: single-word-requests, psychology

There's a type of question I've seen on YouTube (but can't find now) that is asked like a brainteaser, but is too easy to be really called a "brainteaser", but some (a small minority) people (including apparently normal healthy educated native speaker adults) surprisingly cannot solve no matter how many tries they are given.

Here's some examples.

1. Q: If you have traveled for one hour at sixty miles per hour, how far have you traveled?
   A: Sixty miles.
2. Q: A patch of weeds in a field doubles in area each day. After 20 days it fills the field.How many days did it take for the weeds to cover half the area of the field?
   A: This one is a fun one, so you need to scroll down to see the answer labelled with a "*". Note, this one might be a little bit too challenging to be an ideal example of what I am talking about.

They are in a sense tests of English, in that they test knowledge of what "miles per hour", and "doubles is area each day" mean in English and little else. But "English question" doesn't seem right, especially since being a native speaker of English seems not to guarantee ability to solve the question. They are not exactly tricky for most people, so "trick question" and "tricky question" also doesn't seem right either, because no matter how many tries the person is given, they *cannot* solve it. Thus it is not really a case of inattentiveness, but rather "inattentiveness" (in quotes), if you take my meaning.

I have tried Googling, "antibrainteaser" but that doesn't bring up the sort of questions I am looking for. "Trick question" works well to find these sorts of question, but mixed in with a lot of questions that I would call riddles, and others that I'd call true trick question and others that I'd call jokes, for example Q: "How many letters are in the alphabet? A: Eleven (“the alphabet”).

What would be a good name for this type of question/puzzle that is this specific type of trick question or perhaps is not even a trick question although very close to one?

"*" Answer: The first of the two two- digit numbers referred to in the title of that novel by Eric Blair (his real name, though he wrote under a pen name) that was his bestselling novel.

Comment: The second one is a 'trick question' in that it is deliberately worded so as to make the inattentive listener misinterpret what is being asked. It reminds me of one my aunt tried on me many years ago - "If a plane crashed on the border between two countries, where would the survivors be buried?"

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are simple questions, but these are imho still trick questions intended to catch someone off guard.

Comment: (answers at duplicate: 'trivial'; 'no-brainer' ....

Comment: @KateBunting You have a point. It's worded so that it looks a lot like it's a subtraction problem (15 - 7 = 8). It's absurd to ask how many are still alive straight after saying how many are still alive and this cues the "inattentive" (a good diplomatic word; why didn't I think of that?) listener to misinterpret the question. I regret including this example. It is close to your "survivors be buried" question, but not as much of a trick question because it doesn't make a counterfactual assumption. Googling "trick question" worked well to get the sort of questions I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @NVZ The second question certainly is phrased in such a way to cause the inattentive listener to misinterpret it. Furthermore, I've seen that exact question on a webpage of "trick questions". But the first question whose answer is "Sixty miles" seems different. I don't see anything tricky about it. Do you? In what what way, if any, is it designed to catch someone off guard? Sure, the *intention* is to ask an easy question that the interlocutor can't solve, but that not a property of the question. "Trick question" works as a search term so thanks for that, but it's not specific enough, IMHO.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I edited the question extensively. If there were answers at the alleged duplicate, I don't think that's still the case, so please consider voting to reopen the question.

Comment: A [**gimmie**](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gimmie) is a golf putt that is so easy that your opponent doesn't even make you try; they just give you the stroke. I've seen it used in other situations to mean a task or feat or puzzle (in this case) that is trivially easy.

Comment: @CanadianYankee To be a perfect analogy to the "sixty miles" question, you'd want a golf putt that is a gimmie but a minority of people can't get it in the hole no matter how many tries they are given. I've seen on YouTube the sixty miles question put to someone umpteen times, and every imaginable answer except "sixty miles" was given.

Comment: The second example now is nowhere near as trivial as the first, skewing the question appreciably. Why is it included? / I don't see why 'gimme', 'trivial' and 'no-brainer' don't apply to the original question. Phrases include 'piece of cake', 'child's play', 'turkey shoot' .... Perhaps you want _pons asinorum_: << Pons asinorum is also used metaphorically for a problem or challenge which acts as a test of critical thinking in a field, separating capable and incapable reasoners; it represents a test of ability or understanding.... >>[[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum)]

Comment: Perhaps the emphasis is better placed on the individuals not able to solve this one particular problem (though they would still be considered 'capable reasoners'): one would say they had a _mental block_ here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I included the second example because, with the qualification that it is at the hard end of the spectrum of this yet to be name type of question, it does arguably count as a question so easy that no one should be unable to solve it *given an unlimited number of tries*. And even if it's too hard, it helps clarify what I mean. I just don't know that many questions that are obvious, and not trick or even tricky, but some (seemingly) normal people can't *ever* solve. "Gimme", "trivial" etc. don't imply that some normal people cannot ever solve them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Pons asinorum sounds right ("bridge of asses" literally) but actually refers to something quite hard from mathematics. I think my type of question would indicate that the person if they cannot *ever* solve it would in fact indicate that they were *not* capable reasoners (though still normal educated people). I think of a mental block as an emotional problem. It's a possible explanation for what I saw on YouTube, but I took it to be simply as case of innumeracy/ unmechanicalness/scientific illiteracy.

Comment: If they're not capable reasoners at such a basic level, I don't see how they can be classified as 'normal people'. Though we all have blindspots at certain junctures.

Comment: There is a similar claim that there are puzzles that a Kindergartener can answer, but a college educated adult finds maddening. Example: What's greater than God, more evil than the Devil, the poorest poor people have it, but even modestly rich people don't, and if you eat it you die.

Comment: @jimm101 I wouldn't call that a puzzle, but a riddle, and one that does not make sense strictly speaking and therefore a sort of joke. I heard it a few years ago and couldn't solve it, but I don't think that reflects badly on me. Conversely, I can believe that kindergarteners find it easier to solve than graduates do, but that doesn't reflect well on those kids,  :)

Comment: The 'classic Monty Hall' problem is known to throw even some maths teachers, but can be explained to some children to their satisfaction. It is _counterintuitive_.

Comment: @KateBunting The other classic trick question is the one that starts "You're driving a bus", continues with describing how many passengers get on and off at each stop, then ends with "What's the name of the bus driver?"

Comment: There are two busses driving toward each other from some distance away. One bus is driving 35 mph, and the other is 20 miles west of the ocean. A bird jumps off the first bus and flies at 100 mph toward the second bus. When it reaches the second bus, it immediately turns around and flies 100 mph back to the first bus. It keep oscillating between the two busses at that constant speed. One bus changes its speed every few miles, and the other occasionally makes a wrong turn. After an hour, the busses collide head first. How far did the bird fly? The answer is trivial. There is no trick.

Comment: @jimm101 - Well, the 'trick', in the sense in which I meant it, is the inclusion of all that confusing detail about the buses.

Comment: Just because a problem is easy does not mean no skill is required to solve it. And some people would just rather not put in the effort.